# Mysql Request with 'flexible' WHERE clauses and % match

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working on a Mysql database and I'm trying to run a query with 'flexible' WHERE conditions to get at the end a % match with my original query. Let me explain maybe more clearly with an example:

- Let's say I have a table of users with 5 different skills with ID, Name, usergroup, skill1, skill2, skill3, skill4, skill5. The columns skill[N] represents the level of skill and ranges from 1 to 3.
- If for example, I want to search for users from a certain usergroup with skill2 at level 3, skill4 at level 1 and skill5 at level 1, I would run:

  ```
  SELECT * 
  FROM users 
  WHERE usergroup = 10 
  AND skill2 = 3 
  AND skill4 = 1 
  AND skill5 = 1
  ```
- But what I would like is to return more rows that these which matched these strict criteria, byt with a '% match' with my original query.
- For example if a row only has the first 2 skill criteria matched, this would return the row with a 'match variable' of 66% match (assuming all skills equally weighted). If 3 skill criteria are matched, this would give 100%.

The request has to return the rows ordered by 'match' DESC at the end.

Would you know how to do that?

Thank you!

Paganel

Comment: Please provide data setup in sqlfiddle, it will help. Sample data is needed.

Comment: It would be a lot simpler if you normalised your schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by filtering on the minimum acceptance criteria, computing an agreement score, and ordering by the score.  Do note that "match" is a MySQL keyword; if you want to assign it as a column name then you need to quote it.  The result could look like this

```
SELECT *,
  CAST((case skill2 when 3 then 1 else 0 end)
      + (case skill4 when 1 then 1 else 0 end) 
      + (case skill5 when 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS FLOAT) / 3.0 AS "match"
FROM users
WHERE usergroup = 10 AND (skill2 = 3 OR skill4 = 1 OR skill5 = 1)
ORDER BY "match" DESC
```

Comment: You don't need to make it a subquery to `ORDER BY match DESC`; and could use a HAVING to filter out `match` values below a specific threshold.

Comment: Right you are, @Uueerdo.  Answer revised accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Substitute Value1-5 for your data, ensuring you place NULL value in for records you don't want to in consideration.

if you add a where clause, be sure to use OR on skill match, or wrap the whole select as an inline view, return skills individually as well and then limit.

This dynamically takes care of which fields to evaluate in percentage, you just have to identify each of the 5 skills values, or null.

```
Select yourdata, 
(Case when skill1=coalesce(Value1,-1) then 1 else 0 end +
Case when skill2=coalesce(Value2,-1) then 1 else 0 end +
Case when skill3=coalesce(Value3,-1) then 1 else 0 end +
Case when skill4=coalesce(Value4-1) then 1 else 0 end +
Case when skill5=coalesce(Value5-1) then 1 else 0 end) /  
(case when coalesce(value1,0)>0 then 1 else 0 end+
case when coalesce(value2,0)>0 then 1 else 0 end
case when coalesce(value3,0)>0 then 1 else 0 end
case when coalesce(value4,0)>0 then 1 else 0 end
case when coalesce(value5,0)>0 then 1 else 0 end) as PercentMatch
FROM usergroup
ORDER BY PercentMatch Desc
```

Comment: `ORDER BY PercentMatch` would have saved quite a bit of duplication, and not have required any potential changes needed to be made twice.

Comment: It's odd, sometimes I've tried this and It doesn't seem to work, so I fall back to the including the full syntax as part of the order by... but clearly mySQL says it should work: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html